# Is it possible to run 3 terminals (monitor+keyboard+mouse) on a single Ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I am totally new to Linux and I am trying to set up a studying environment for my kids.

I am thinking of buying one PC, install an Ubuntu server (GUI) on it and then connect 3 terminals to it, each of which can run applications separately from others. Each terminal is a monitor + keyboard + mouse only, no PC.

Any advice?

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multiseat and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions

Comment: Nowadays I would buy a license for a google/amazon/azure instance :-) The price of the server would pay for the license and then some